# gem update --system error in bash for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, bash, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Using `bash` on windows. I'm stuck at configuring my environment to get started with ruby on rails. I've installed the ruby and rails but still caught in problems. Details mentioned below

Executed commands and their result is pasted below.

```
ruby -v

ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]

gem install bundler

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String

gem update --system

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String

rails s

Rails 2.4.0 `<main>': undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)**
```

So actually what is the problem?

Comment: What guide did you follow to setup your Rails environment for Windows?

Comment: I followed https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10 and installed rails using rbenv method. Then I cloned a ROR repository from github and updated my gems version.

I just came to know that my rails setup is not installed now anymore. Because of following result.


 rails -v

/home/ghost/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>': undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)